# awakeFromNib can't get value from UILabel and can't disable UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, iboutlet, xcode4.6, awakefromnib

I have two buttons in single-view app main storyboard and would like to disable one of them as well as get value from the UILabel using awakeFromNib method. As far as I concern all relationships and GUI items must be initialized and values must be assigned before calling the awake method. Unfortunately I am not able to do get the value and disable button by applying

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
     decreaseButton.enabled = NO;
     decreaseButton.alpha = 0.2;
     [polygon initWithNumberOfSides:numberOfSidesLabel.text.integerValue     
               minimumNumberOfSides:3
               maximumNumberOfSides:12]; 
}
```

to the class I have made. I have established the connection between the UILabel and

```
IBOutlet UILabel *numberOfSidesLabel;
```

in my created class file. 
Can somebody see the mistake or shall I provide more info on the problem?

Comment: Are `decreaseButton` and `numberOfSidesLabel` nil when `-awakeFromNib` is called?

Comment: The label has initial value of "3" in UI but when awake is called the value is 0. Buttons have relationship with actions: increase & decrease.

Comment: Is the value 0, or does it just look like it's zero because you're calling methods on a nil object?

Comment: NSLog(@"%i",numberOfSidesLabel.text.integerValue);
returns 0

Comment: One of the important things to know about Objective-C that is different from other languages is that it is perfectly legal to call a method on a variable that is set to `nil`.  Roughly speaking, all such method calls return 0 or nil.  So it's important here to know if `numberOfSidesLabel` is itself nil, or if it is actually an instantiated `UILabel` object with label text that evaluates to 0.  Add something like: `NSLog(@"%@", numberOfSidesLabel);` or use the debugger to check.

Comment: If the NSLog(@"%@", numberOfSidesLabel); is called in awakeFromNib the result is (null) if I try to access UILabel after app is loaded
 
<UILabel: 0x7577550; frame = (170 39; 42 21); text = '3'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7577aa0>>

it has value "3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must call `[super awakeFromNib];` when you override this method.

Second, standard practice is to use `viewDidLoad`. Try that instead.

Comment: Thank You for you response.

I tried to call UILabel :

 NSLog(@"%i",numberOfSidesLabel.text.integerValue);

inside viewDidLoad but result = 0;

when everything is loaded I have no issues to get the value from label and pass it further, but not in compile time.

Comment: So what's the problem. You need it at runtime, not compile time. Is the problem the conversion to integer?

Comment: I need to do some set up (disable the button and get the value of UILabel) before the app is started. I am not able to to both of these tasks and cannot identify where am I wrong.

Comment: You should not get any *value* from a *UI element* at startup! If you need to persist a value across application starts, use `NSUserDefaults`. Populate your UI (e.g. label) when you configure your view before it appears.

Comment: That's where I was wrong, thank you for your help. I got the idea and see where I was wrong now.